# Javascript profiling iOS 8 Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, mobile-safari

I'm attempting to fix some performance issues in our HTML5 game under iOS 8. I've got the Yosemite beta, and Safari 8.0 on a Mac. I seem to have lost the JS Profiling tool. According to the iOS developer center:

> To start profiling manually, click the record button in the top right of the Profiles pane, and select Start JavaScript Profile in the resulting menu.

(from [here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Instruments/Instruments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH4-SW7))

On Safari 8, I don't get a menu with that option, it just starts recording a timeline. Where has this moved to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would seem as if the profiling has been replaced with the "Records"-section which provide some of the same info, although not all of it.

As mentioned in the comments, in order to find the Records section click Timelines, then JavaScript & Events in the timelines which will show "Records" in the lower left corner.

Comment: Where is that "Records" section? Can't find anything in the debugger or timelines..

Comment: Found it: select JavaScript & Events, click one of the frames and expand the call tree on the left..

Comment: Ah, yes. Should have maybe included that in my answer ;) I'll update it.