# Aggregating Javascript "records" from iOS 8 Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, profiling

I'm trying to profile a WebGL application on iOS Safari through the WebInspector on desktop Safari 8.0.5. As [others have concluded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970466/javascript-profiling-ios-8-safari), the standard "profiles" pane has been removed and replaced with the "Records" pane. The Records pane just shows the call stack, but I need a profile with the possibility to aggregate records. Is there any way of bringing that "old style" profiling behaviour back into Safari 8 or is there any way for me to use the data from the Safari 8 Web Inspector, e.g. in xcode?

It is important that the profile comes from an actual iOS Device, since I especially want to profile `gl`context calls like `gl.texImage2D` etc.

Comment: [You might want to read this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819866/measure-webgl-texture-load-in-ms/29916151#29916151)

Comment: Good read, but that is very specific for one part of the code. I would like to do something similar to what I can do in chrome, and apparently in older versions of Safari, i.e. listing all executed functions and aggregating them by % of execution time.

Comment: Sure but it won't actually tell you the times for WebGL functions. It will only tell you how long it took JavaScript to insert a command into a command buffer. It will not tell you how long that operation took. I can make a draw command that takes 30 minutes to execute but it will only take JavaScript a few nano seconds to add the command and that's all that will show up in the profiler.

Comment: That's true, but in chrome for example I get something called "(program)" in the profiler. I though that was the actual draw execution, but I may be wrong here. Tried the answer you linked for a couple of gl calls and got some results at least.

Comment: Seems like (program) is a grouped profile for global/native function calls as explained e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847954/chrome-debugger-what-is-program-in-the-profiler). I guess I misinterpreted it as a _shader_-program